# editurl:'client array' data to be shown in jqgrid but should not save that data to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

var specificatonsData = [];

```
function initGridForTransactions(gridID, gridPagerID) {
    var grid_selector = gridID;
    var pager_selector = gridPagerID;

    $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
        $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#page-wrapper").width());
    })

    var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');
    $(document).on('settings.ace.jqGrid', function (ev, event_name, collapsed) {
        if (event_name === 'sidebar_collapsed' || event_name === 'main_container_fixed') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', parent_column.width());
            }, 0);
        }
    })

    $(grid_selector).jqGrid({
        data: specificatonsData,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['Id','Specification', 'Abbreviation'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id',  width: 80,key:true },
            { name: 'specification', index: 'Id', key: true, width: 300 },
            { name: 'abbreviation', width: 300 },
        ],
        cmTemplate: { editable: true },
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 4000,
        gridview: true,
        rowList: [4000],
        pager: pager_selector,
        altRows: true,
        loadonce: true,
        multiselect: false,
        multiboxonly: false,
        sortname: 'Specification',
        sortorder: "asc",
        cellEdit: false,
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        onSelectRow: function (rowId, status, e) {
            var dealerFeatures = $("#editor").text();
            var selectedFeature = rowId;
            selectedFeature = selectedFeature.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
            var pattern = new RegExp("(" + selectedFeature + ")", "gi");
            dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
            //dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1<mark>$2</mark>$4");
            dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(/(<mark>[<>]*)((<[>]+>)+)([<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1<mark>$2</mark>$4");

            dealerFeatures = dealerFeatures.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');
            $("#editor").html(dealerFeatures);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            $(grid_selector).setColProp('Approve', { editoptions: { value: '' } });
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var table = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                updatePagerIcons(table);
                enableTooltips(table);
            }, 0);
        },
    }).navGrid(pager_selector, { edit: true, add: true, del: false },
        {
            url: '/Activity/SaveSpecification',
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            afterSubmit: function () {
                getAbbrData();
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        });
    jQuery(grid_selector).sortableRows();

    function updatePagerIcons(table) {
        var replacement =
            {
                'ui-icon-seek-first': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-next': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-end': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140'
            };
        $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
            var icon = $(this);
            var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));

            if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
        })
    }

    function enableTooltips(table) {
        $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
        $(table).find('.ui-pg-div').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
    }

    $(document).one('ajaxloadstart.page', function (e) {
        $(grid_selector).jqGrid('GridUnload');
        $('.ui-jqdialog').remove();
    });
}
```

I will save data to database only when I click on external Submit button.

When I click on edit button the data is showing in a popup and when I click on the save button the data is getting to the database and showing in the jqgrid.

But I have a new requirement where I have to show the data in the jqgrid when click on save button but should not save to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://www.guriddo.net) then you can set url in edit options in your navigator  to be clientArray - i.e

```
...navGrid(pager_selector, { edit: true, add: true, del: false },
    {
        url: 'clientArray',
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmit: function () {
            getAbbrData();
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
});
```

This will save the data locally.

Answer (score 0):

The code, which you posted contains many small bugs. For example,

- you use `url: '/Activity/SaveSpecification'` as form Edit options (not for Add form) - see `navGrid` call. You should remove the option to make `editurl: 'clientArray'` working
- you use `key:true` in more as one column. It's not allowed. One can use it only in **one** column, which contains **unique** values.
- the usage of `index: 'Id'` property in `colModel` for the column `name: 'specification'` is probably one more bug, which can make wrong sorting and filtering in the column.
- your current code contains call of `.setColProp('Approve', { ... });`, which is wrong, because your `colModel` don't contains the column `'Approve'`
- the option `sortname: 'Specification'` is wrong too, because the value of `sortname` should be the value of `name` property from `colModel` (like `sortname: 'specification'` for example, if you'll remove `index: 'Id'` property from the column).

Additionally the usage of `rowNum: 4000` can essentially reduce the performance of the grid in case of large grid. If real number of rows is about 4000, then it's much more effective to use local paging of data. The monitor allows to display only about 20-25 rows. Thus it's recommended to use `pager` with such small `rowNum`. Users can use paging buttons to go to the next page.